# dividing sections in html form

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have divided my html page into 3 section with specified height as coded below. Now I want to place my next piece of code as below of above section and also in middle of web page. But I am not able to get expected data.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#left {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#center {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#right {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#tablediv {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">ID <input type="text" id="grn" class="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" autofocus="autofocus" /><br><br> Type
  <select name="evalu" id="evalu">
 <option value="electrical">Electrical</option>
 <option value="mechanical">Mechanical</option>
</select><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="find" value="Find" class="button0" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id="center">
  Name: <input type="hidden" id="name" class="tb1" /><br><br> Section : <input type="hidden" id="sec" class="tb1" /><br><br> V.Inv.No <input type="hidden" name="vinvno" id="vinvno" class="tb1" /><br><br> V.Inv.Date <input type="hidden" name="vinvdt" id="vinvdt"
    class="tb1" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id="right">
  IRno: <input type="hidden" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="tb1" maxlength="8" /><br><br> IDate <input type="date" name="idt" id="idt" class="tb1" value="<%= new SimpleDateFormat(" dd-MM-yyyy ").format(new java.util.Date())%>"><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" class="button0" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id="tablediv">
  <input type="button" value="Show Item List" id="showTable" class="button0" />
  <table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="btnSelect" id="chk" name="chkOrgRow" /></td>
      <th scope="col"> SIno</th>
      <th scope="col">Item name</th>
      <th scope="col">Item code</th>
      <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
      <th scope="col">Received qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Accepted qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Rejected qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

[modified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9rZ7.png)

Comment: Can you share some image how you want the web-page to look like? Sorry, but I can't seem to understand.

Comment: What does the "middle" in "also in middle of web page" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#tablediv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

It will keep the tablediv in the middle between the top content and the page.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 30%;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
}

#left {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#center {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}

#right {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 786px) {
  #tablediv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="left">ID <input type="text" id="grn" class="tb1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)" autofocus="autofocus" /><br><br> Type
  <select name="evalu" id="evalu">
 <option value="electrical">Electrical</option>
 <option value="mechanical">Mechanical</option>
</select><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="find" value="Find" class="button0" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id="center">
  Name: <input type="hidden" id="name" class="tb1" /><br><br> Section : <input type="hidden" id="sec" class="tb1" /><br><br> V.Inv.No <input type="hidden" name="vinvno" id="vinvno" class="tb1" /><br><br> V.Inv.Date <input type="hidden" name="vinvdt" id="vinvdt"
    class="tb1" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id="right">
  IRno: <input type="hidden" name="irepno" id="irepno" class="tb1" maxlength="8" /><br><br> IDate <input type="date" name="idt" id="idt" class="tb1" value="<%= new SimpleDateFormat(" dd-MM-yyyy ").format(new java.util.Date())%>"><br><br>
  <input type="button" id="search" value="Search" class="button0" /><br><br>
</div>
<div id="tablediv">
  <input type="button" value="Show Item List" id="showTable" class="button0" />
  <table cellspacing="0" id="itemtable" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" class="btnSelect" id="chk" name="chkOrgRow" /></td>
      <th scope="col"> SIno</th>
      <th scope="col">Item name</th>
      <th scope="col">Item code</th>
      <th scope="col">Supplier</th>
      <th scope="col">Received qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Accepted qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Rejected qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Remarks</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: updated with media query so that on lower screens it is not absolute.

Comment: when i tried to populate some values in tablediv tables, then that division is going to right corner. please help me on this. added an image

Comment: :have u changed this part alone  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); ? still i am getting same . actually those <td> will be loaded dynamically when click above button. so at that time..based on <td> size its moving right side. if<td> length is more then it covers page correctly

Comment: top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);

Comment: and also its giving different behavior in chrome and mozila. please help me to how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the css code as below:

```
#tablediv {
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: thanks. but this div goes to the bottom of the screen